# evitar escalamiento en matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy tratando hacer el siguiente gráfico sin embargo matplotlib, reescala todo, quisiera saber como evitar eso gracias.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([15,20,25,30,35,40,45])
y = np.array([-5169.45991525,-5169.25042889,-5169.23521166,-5169.23374842,-5169.23372181, -5169.23355290,-5169.23353987])
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image: imagen]

Answer (score 0):

para evitar que escale, utiliza:

```
plt.autoscale(False)
```

De tal forma que tú código, quedaría así:

```
    matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    x = np.array([15,20,25,30,35,40,45])
    y = np.array([-5169.45991525,-5169.25042889,-5169.23521166,-5169.23374842,-5169.23372181, -5169.23355290,-5169.23353987])
    
    plt.autoscale(False)

    #Escalamos los ejes a los número que tú quieras.
    plt.ylim(-6000, 0)
    plt.xlim(15, 45)
    
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Hola intenté hacer lo que me dijiste pero obtuve una grafica vacia

Comment: disculpa, me falto escalar el eje de las x y las y a lo que tu quieras, te he modificado la respuesta